# Eclipse: change vertical bar color

Tags: eclipse

trying to deal with a minor issue here: I want to make my eclipse as distraction free as possible. So far I'm satisfied, except for one thing that I've not been able to figure out how to change:

[image: eclipse screenshot with white annoying bars]

the white vertical bars are ... annoying. How can I change their color?

Please note that the left ruler is not the code folding bar (which is on the right side of the line numbers), but the so called "vertical ruler" which shows line annotations (eg errors and stuff), to be found in Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations. This bar can not be deactivated (which I don"t want because i find it useful), I just want its color changed. Don't know what the right ruler is though.

not a duplicate of [Vertical white line on eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490672/vertical-white-line-on-eclipse) or [Is it possible to make Eclipse's code-folding gutter black?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041760/is-it-possible-to-make-eclipses-code-folding-gutter-black)

edit: but indeed a (partial) duplicate of [Change overview ruler color in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204548/change-overview-ruler-color-in-eclipse?rq=1). Problem not solved: changing the system theme (mine is mediterranean dark) did not change the color of the bar.

Thank you

Comment: How did you change the system theme?

Comment: i use lxappearance to change the gtk themes

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found it myself, sharing it for others who want to customize their bar color:

```
#org-eclipse-e4-ui-compatibility-editor * { background-color: #002b36; }
```

change the hex value to anything you like. This css snippet has to be added to eclipse in some way (I did it with eclipse Chrome Theme http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-4-chrome-theme#.UYrzEkAW1J0)

FYI: I found the css id with the "css spy" from the eclipse tooling collection (http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-4-tools-css-spy#.UYrzSkAW1J0)

result:

[image: styled eclipse]

Comment: This also changes the background color of the editor, but it's good enough.

Answer (score 9):

Btw, It looks like you can actually just disable this bar by going to Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors. Then just uncheck the box labeled "Show range indicator".

Comment: This should have been the chosen answer. Thanks mate.

Comment: The author explicitly says he doesn't want to disable it because he finds it useful. He just wants to change the color.

Comment: Google sent me here in my attempts to find a solution to removing that bar, so even though it's not the exact answer to Eike's issue, I think this deserves to be recognized. I would likely have spent *hours* trying to figure out which Eclipse preference to disable to get rid of that thing.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for sharing your solution. I could apply the code by just adding to CSS files in `eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.3.1.v20130911-1000\css`.

I use Windows 7 theme so added to `e4_default_win7.css`. And I slightly modified the rule to have less side effect (occurrence markers were hard to see with the colors set by color theme).

```
#org-eclipse-e4-ui-compatibility-editor Composite > Canvas {
    background-color: #232323;
}
```

Comment: How does the filename get interpreted? I'm using Linux, so I'm not sure what to name it. I tried `e4_default_linux.css` and `e4_default_rhel.css` to no avail.

Comment: The CSS is chosen according to the value of Window > Preferences > Appearance > Theme. I don't use Eclipse on Unix-like OS so not sure but `e4_default.css` would be used by the Default Theme and `e4_default_gtk.css` for GTK theme.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but for me with Neon .2 on windows it was the unfold bar that stayed white. After I disabled unfold and enabled it, the bar stayed black(for now). But you could also just keep it disabled. It is shown in the link below.

[image]
 [link to the PrntScrn to disable unfold bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stwgw.jpg)