# Eclipse change color of vertical white line

Tags: eclipse

I've applied a custom code coloring theme to eclipse 4.3 (Kepler), but there is this annoying thin vertical white line separating code and line numbers. Is it possible to change it's color somehow?

I'm on Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) 64bit, Java 1.7_45 64bit

[image]

**UPDATE:** I've installed Chrome Theme which allows certain customisation, so I was thinking maybe there is a css to change that line color?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse: change vertical bar color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449728/eclipse-change-vertical-bar-color). There seem to be a couple of questions related to this, but this looks like a duplicate question of the linked item

Comment: @Petesh It's not the vertical BAR, it's the line that is completely separate thing.

Comment: You're talking about the line that is from top-to-bottom of the screen there that is colored white? If that's the case, then the linked question should address the issue. If you're talking about the cursor caret, then that's a different question.

Comment: @Petesh the bar in your question goes on the left side of the white vertical line in my screenshot and it's colored right. Don't confuse two different issues.

Answer (score 0):

That white (it's not white actually but #F8F8F8) line was haunting my dark theme. Google sent me here but couldn't find a working solution. But I found some clues as to where to look for a solution. If you're running Eclipse on Windows 7, there's a file called **e4_default_win7.css** inside one of the folders. Just search for it.

In that file the last section is,

```
CTabFolder Canvas {
    background-color: #28446a;
}
```

Just change the color there. That'll solve the problem. I actually did this for my TrueStudio Eclipse IDE. But this leaves another problem. The text is too close to the line numbers and I don't know how to change the margin between them!

[Screenshot - see what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfvbT.png)